# Output database results over multiple pages

Tags: php, mysql

How would I output the selected data from the database over a certain amount of pages.

For example I'd like 20 result per page and it automatically adds the extra pages needed (bit like google search pages but no search is needed as I am getting everything from the database).

Sorry for a bad explanation and also badly indented code, new to stackoverflow. I've tried putting just the php, rest of the page isn't complete or I removed the unnecessary code, feel free to improve as well.

At the moment I am just calling all the data onto one page using very simple 
code

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['Username']);
    session_destroy();
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Backend</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="" style="min-width: 1024px; max-width: 1920px; margin: 0 auto; min-height: 1280px; max-height: 1080px;">

    <?php
    if (isset ($_SESSION['Username']))
    {
    ?>

    <button onclick="location.href = 'logout.php';">Logout</button>



    <?php
    if (isset ($_SESSION['Username']))
    {
    echo "";

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "request";


    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }




    $sql = "SELECT * FROM request";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM request ORDER BY id DESC";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    if (isset ($_SESSION['Username']))
    {
    ?>


        <div align="center">
       <div class="requests">
       <p><?php echo $row["Name"]; ?></p>

        <p><?php echo $row["Number"]; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $row["Song"]; ?></p>
        </div>

    </div>





    <?php
        }else{
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 requests";
    }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: Search 'Pagination PHP'

Comment: I've tried that, tried looking at w3schools as they are quite good but I cant find anything very helpful as the descriptions are very vague (bit like my question) and I don't understand it. I'd rather 'steal' code and understand it than take code that I don't understand

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Pagination+PHP+site:stackoverflow.com any of these help?

Answer (score 2):

Let's see an example of pagination in PHP. Before that, we need to understand what pagination is. Result pagination is quite simple.

We do a search on a certain DataBase table, and with the result of the search, we divide the number of records by a specific number to display per page.
Related: Data pagination in PHP and MVC

For example a total of 200 records, and we want to display 20 per page, we will soon have 200/20 = 10 pages. Simple, right? Well let's go to the code then.

First connect to MySQL:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("host","user","pass");
$db = mysql_select_db("database");
?>
```

Now let's create the SQL clause that should be executed:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
?>
```

Let's get to work ... Specify the total number of records to show per page:

```
<?php
$total_reg = "10"; // number of records per page
?>
```

If the page is not specified the variable "page" will take a value of 1, this will avoid displaying the start page 0:

```
  <?php
    $page=$_GET['page'];
    if (!$page) {
    $pc = "1";
    } else {
    $pc = $page;
    }
    ?>
```

Let's determine the initial value of the limited searches:

```
<?php
$begin = $pc - 1;
$begin = $begin * $total_reg;
?>
```

Let's select the data and display the pagination:

```
<?php
$limit = mysql_query("$query LIMIT $begin,$total_reg");
$all = mysql_query("$query");

$tr = mysql_num_rows($all); // checks the total number of records
$tp = $tr / $total_reg; // checks the total number of pages

// let's create visualization
while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($limit)) {
$name = $data["name"];
echo "Name: $name<br>";
}

// now let's create the "Previous and next"
$previous = $pc -1;
$next = $pc +1;
if ($pc>1) {
echo " <a href='?page=$previous'><- Previous</a> ";
}
echo "|";
if ($pc<$tp) {
echo " <a href='?page=$next'>Next -></a>";
}
?>
```

Ready, your pagination in PHP is created!

Comment: Thanks, the code seems good and I've changed the bits that I think I needed to change to make to code connect to the database but nothing is being shown and there are no connection errors to the database

Comment: Okay, but did you check the part that explained how to do paging? maybe the problem is there and not in the query sql database. I also advise you to study frameworks that will help you in the creation process more simple and organized, I use Laravel and recommend. Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/

Comment: Ok so I've tried looking at it and went through checking where the code stops and found that it stop at the part:

$limit = mysql_query("$query LIMIT $begin,$total_reg");
$all = mysql_query("$query");

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: also can you explain this piece of code in a bit more detail: $page=$_GET['page'];
    if (!$page) {
    $pc = "1";
    } else {
    $pc = $page;
    } I have also changed the database connection to <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "request";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } but that is all i have changed

Comment: @Oliver.Kirkpatrick Well, I dont kown, but you can try this: mysqli_query rather than mysql_query. Try it

Comment: @Oliver.Kirkpatrick This part of the code refers to the capture of the page parameter that is passed by url when clicking the page. If it is different from the page, it assigns the value 1 to the pc variable, otherwise it assigns the page value to the pc variable.

Comment: Ok and also changing mysql to msqli works for the most part apart from the visualization

Comment: Almost its just having problems with the visualization. It does the "|" but doesnt echo next or anything or any of th data

Comment: perhaps because this condition (if ($pc<$tp) {
echo " <a href='?page=$next'>Next -></a>";
} ) is not happening, check the value of $pc and $tp

Comment: How do I check that value?

Comment: You can print this value on your html for test. Like echo $pc . ' ' . $tp

Comment: Sorry its been so long, but printing out the value gives me 1  0, is this correct?